# Animating SurfaceView with MediaPlayer inside

Tags: java, android, animation

In my application I am using MediaPlayer and SurfaceView with online video streaming. In the beggining, I am stretching SurfaceView to match the parent layout's screen height; when I click it, I want my SurfaceView to change it's size to match screen width (all the time preserving proportions). Resizing works as intended, so I added animation. And animation also works as intended... except for MediaPlayer inside, which changes it's size in different pace than SurfaceView.

Effect is, my SurfaceView scales as it should through time (I gave it a try without MediaPlayer pinned to it), but MediaPlayer video is scaling a bit faster than SurfaceView, which causes shaking effect (faster the transition, more shaky it becomes). Is there any way to control how does MediaPlayer draw itself on surface?

Comment: If that will help - as far as I remember VideoView had no such problem, it was resizing perfectly fine (unfortunately using it is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this just in case anyone will have same problems - change your SurfaceView to TextureView. TV is as easy to use as SV, but works MUCH better with animations (seems like SV can't handle them as good as TV does).